# In-memory Database Tables in java

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I am totally new to Hibernate , so this question might seem so naive for someone.

I am developing an application that requires in-memory tables, and writing the tables to disc only a periodic intervals to reduce write operations. I could have done this using some complex datastructures, but since ultimately my data is stored in database on a disc, I am searching for any in-memory Database computation feature in Java. Does Hibernate allow me to do this?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you are looking for a hypersonic / HSQL in memory database. If you use this then you can set a property called write delay that will delay the write to disk like this:

```
<property name="connection.writedelay">100</property>
```

Have a look [here](http://hsqldb.org/).

Comment: a good example to see how to use this is to setup the Spring Roo 10 minute demo and have a look at the configuration files that it generates for you. This demo uses an in memory DB. For more info see this link: http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/intro.html.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can use Hypersonic SQL in in-memory mode.